# Difficulty Using Python Split String Method

Tags: python

I hate that I have to ask such a basic question, but I can't seem to get the split method to work in python.

I have a dictionary, when I print it, it looks like:

```
data_dict = <QueryDict: {u'ids': [u'1012,738'], u'ct': [u'9']}>
```

I want to create an array of id objects from the 'ids' list, as in:

```
ids = [1012, 738]
```

It appears that the list 'ids' is really just a string of ids separated by commas, so I tried:

```
id_string = data_dict['ids']
ids = id_string.split(',')
for id in ids:
    print(id)
```

Nothing prints.  Then I thought, perhaps the u' means its not a string and I need to convert it to a string first to get split to work, so I tried:

```
id_string = data_dict['ids']
id_string = str(id_string)
ids = id_string.split(',')
for id in ids:
    print(id)
```

Nothing prints. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[u'1012,738']` is a list so you've to use `id_string = data_dict['ids'][0]` to get the first element from that list.

To convert the items of that string into list of integers use either `map` or a `list comprehension`:

```
#map
map(int, data_dict['ids'][0].split(','))

#LC
[int(x) for x in data_dict['ids'][0].split(',')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> strs = '1012,738'
>>> map(int, strs.split(','))
[1012, 738]
>>> [int(x) for x in  strs.split(',')]
[1012, 738]
```

Comment: `data_dict['ids']` returns `[u'1012,738']`, doesn't it?

Comment: thanks! for some reason, data_dict['ids'] returned the string, i didn't need [0].

Comment: @user1697845 glad that helped, looks like `QueryDict` behaves differently than normal dicts.

Answer (score 2):

`data_dict['ids']` seems like it's actually a *list* which contains a string. So try `id_string = data_dict['ids'][0]`.

A `u'foo'` is a Unicode string. It should still have all the normal string methods.

Also, if you're using Django and running the code with `python manage.py runserver` (and not running in production!), you can inject `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into your code. Then, when you load the page, the server output will contain a pdb prompt which you can use to experiment just like in the Python shell.

A small note if you do start using PDB in this manner: PDB has some one-letter commands and other things that will take precedence over Python code. You can use `!` to make sure PDB runs your code like Python. E.g.:

```
(Pdb) list(range(3))
*** Error in argument: '(range(3))'
```

PDB has its own `list` command that you can use to show source code.

```
(Pdb) !list(range(3))
[0, 1, 2]
```

By using `!` first, the command is properly treated like Python.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried using [0], but it still doesn't print.  When i print data_dict['ids'], i just get '1012,738', so I think its automatically just printing [0].

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten but that's probably a convenience feature of the Django `QueryDict` class: if an item is a one-element list it'll give you the item in the list instead of the list, or something like that. That's my guess anyway